# How to make a custom toolbar in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have problems to align items in a toolbar, every created item it's set to right, so I want to know if it is possible to create a custom Toolbar, specifically like this:

[image]

A Text in the middle, and two items, one in the left and one in the right. I edited this picture to understand what I need. 
Hope it's clear

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  What _specific problem_ are you having making it?  What did you try, and what happened when you did?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for making a custom toolbar in Android:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    >

                 <RelativeLayout
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent">

                     <TextView
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                         android:gravity="center"
                         android:text="@string/app_name"
                         android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline5" />

                     <ImageView
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                         android:src=""
                         android:contentDescription="@null"
                         />

                     <ImageView
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                         android:src=""
                         android:contentDescription="@null"
                         />
                 </RelativeLayout>   


                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

P.S.: I have used Androidx, make sure you are using the same too or simply change toolbar to v7 support one.